# If https already encrypted GET request, is sha encryption important?

Tags: security, https, sha

I'm looking at Weixin's document, I found that they are using SHA-1. I feel like it's not secure, but then my friend said 'never mind, we use https', so I am wondering, is it important to use SHA-1 or others? When will https encrypt our request?

Thanks!

This is Weixin's document:
https://developers.weixin.qq.com/doc/offiaccount/en/Basic_Information/Access_Overview.html

```
private function checkSignature()
{
    $signature = $\GET["signature"];
    $timestamp = $\GET["timestamp"];
    $nonce = $\GET["nonce"];
    $token = TOKEN;
    $tmpArr = array($token, $timestamp, $nonce);
    sort($tmpArr, SORT_STRING);
    $tmpStr = implode( $tmpArr );
    $tmpStr = sha1( $tmpStr );
    if( $tmpStr == $signature ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. By the site's rules, each question has to be self-contained, if at all possible. Supplementary links are welcome, but each question needs to make sense even if the link goes dead. Accordingly, could you please edit your question and add the relevant text from your link?

Comment: @Amadan Thanks, I just updated and added relevant code to my question.

Comment: SHA-1 is a one way hash function... though it should not be used in most of the cases but in your case since you are using it as per the recommendation you have no other option but to use it.

Answer (score 0):

SHA-1 is a one way hash function. It should be avoided in most cases, but in your case WeChat doesn't offer you any alternative (though WeChat could of course modify their implementation in the future).

Also to answer your other question, which is when HTTPS encrypts your request; HTTPS is a protocol which ensures that the data in motion is secured and encrypted.

The moment a browser attempts to access a website that is secured by SSL, the browser and the web server get into a sequence of message exchanges which is also known as "SSL Handshake". The SSL Handshake happens behind the scene and it transparent to the user.

The handshake process leads to the establishment of a session key using the public and private key pair. The session key is then used to set up the SSL Connection.

Since symmetric cryptography is more efficient in terms of power, the PKI part is used only during the SSL Handshake to establish the symmetric session key. The data in motion is encrypted using the shared symmetric key.